# Recomputing entity changeset in onFlush listener

Tags: doctrine-orm, changeset, event-listener

Consider the following schema:

```
[Work]
id
tags ManyToMany(targetEntity="Tag", inversedBy="works", cascade={"persist"})

[Tag]
id
works_count
works ManyToMany(targetEntity="Work", mappedBy="tags")
```

`works_count` is a counter cache for `Tag::works`.

I have a `onFlush` listener on **Work** that checks if `Work::tags` has changed, and updates each of the tags' `works_count`.

```
public function onFlush(OnFlushEventArgs $args)
{
    foreach ($uow->getScheduledEntityUpdates() as $work) {
        $changedTags = /* update relevant tags and return all the changed ones */

        $metadata = $em->getClassMetadata('Acme\Entity\Tag');

        foreach ($changedTags as $tag) {
            $uow->recomputeSingleEntityChangeSet($metadata, $tag);
        }
    }
}
```

Now if I read the changesets of the updated tags, the changes of `works_count` appears correctly, **but** they don't get updated in the database..

If I replace `recomputeSingleEntityChangeSet()` with `computeChangeSet()` then everything works as expected and the DB is updated, but [computeChangeSet()](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php#L521) has an `@internal Don't call from the outside.` annotation on it, so I'm not sure what the consequences are..

Every source on the internet says to use `recomputeSingleEntityChangeSet` so why doesn't it work in this case?

**P.S**
The tags are managed by the EntityManager (`$em->contains($tag)` returns true)

Comment: Same here :( I'm not sure what to do

Comment: Woops, I just noticed that with `computeChangeSet()` if the entity already had changes, those changes were ignored :/. So `computeChangeSet()` is not good at all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem was related with a bug in UnitOfWork and finally it's fixed with the release of [Doctrine ORM 2.4.3](http://www.doctrine-project.org/2014/09/11/orm-244.html) on September 11, 2014. See [DDC-2996](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/3760) for details.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that Doctrine 2.2 can merge change sets or generate new change sets, but it needs to know which. If you get it wrong, it will either replace your existing change sets or do nothing at all. I'd be very interested to know if there is a better option than this, or if this is even right.

```
    if($uow->getEntityChangeSet($entity)) {
        /** If the entity has pending changes, we need to recompute/merge. */
        $uow->recomputeSingleEntityChangeSet($meta, $contact);
    } else {
        /** If there are no changes, we compute from scratch? */
        $uow->computeChangeSet($meta, $entity);
    }
```

Comment: But what about the @internal annotation? Is it save to use this method?

Comment: Probably not. But I haven't seen another method. And there also seem to be a few libraries which use @internal Doctrine methods.

Answer (score 1):

In doctrine 2.4.1, use recomputeSingleEntityChangeSet only if you are changing tag in the event listener AND UOW contain tag ChangeSet (Change that happen outside of the event listener). Basically recomputeSingleEntityChangeSet is a function to merge ChangeSet for an entity.

Doc from the function
The passed entity must be a managed entity. If the entity already has a change set because this method is invoked during a commit cycle then the change sets are added whereby changes detected in this method prevail.

NOTE: You need to make sure UOW already have ChangeSet for the entity, otherwise it will not merge.

Answer (score 0):

For future readers, **at all cost** try to **avoid** the **listeners**. Those are hardly testable, your domain should not rely on magic. Consider OP's test case how to achieve the same without Doctrine events:

**Work** class:

```
public function addTag(Tag $tag): void
{
    if (!$this->tags->contains($tag)) {
        $this->tags->add($tag);
        $tag->addWork($this);
    }
}
```

**Tag** class:

```
public function addWork(Work $work): void
{
    if (!$this->works->contains($work)) {
        $work->addTag($this);
        $this->works->add($work);
        $this->worksCount = count($this->works);
    }
}
```

**TagTest** class:

```
public function testItUpdatesWorksCountWhenWorkIsAdded()
{
    $tag = new Tag();

    $tag->addWork(new Work());
    $tag->addWork(new Work());

    $this->assertSame(2, $tag->getWorkCount());
}

public function testItDoesNotUpdateWorksCountIfWorkIsAlreadyInCollection()
{
    $tag = new Tag();
    $work = new Work();
    $tag->addWork($work);

    $tag->addWork($work);

    $this->assertSame(1, $tag->getWorkCount());
}
```